# Stepped wedge design to analyze healthcare intervention rolled out at different times to members?

Tags: panel-data, experiment-design, causality, treatment-effect, case-control-study

I'm working on a pre/post analysis of longitudinal healthcare data where an intervention program was implemented on a member by member basis over a period of several years. Some eligible members received the intervention earlier while others received the intervention later in the study period.

Rather than collect additional member-level data for a control group, which will likely be a very different population (with unmeasured confounders), could I instead estimate the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT) by gathering member-months who have not yet had the intervention at index time $t$ into an ad hoc control group, which will be matched to member-months who did receive the intervention at $t$?

This would be a stepped wedge design clustered at the member-level, is that correct? I'm working with observational data, not a randomized controlled trial, but the same design principles should apply.

Comment: You could also consider a staggered difference-in-difference approach, aka SDID.

Comment: @dimitriy Thanks, I'll look up SDID in the literature. An advantage with staggered treatments is since all subjects are in the trmt group, there are no unmeasured confounders as long as the intervention timing is random & not corelated with the outcome. One drawback is the matching success rate may be a lot lower since our pool of trmt members is much smaller than the control group.